# Numa arquitetura, o número de DLLs influencia em performance? Escalabilidade?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, arquitetura-de-software, escalabilidade

Tenho o costume de criar minha solution assim:

Entity - `Class Library` (Classes,entidades)

Utils - `Class Library`  (Classes de auxilio, segurança, gerar xml, enfim, funções de todo tipo)

Repository - Class de repository ( repository patterns)

Map   - `Class Libary` - Classes de Mapeamento do ORM, seja ele `Nhibernate` ou `Entity` usando `Fluent API`

Test - Test

`Web Project`  - Aqui meu projeto web, se quero separar em "modulo" uso as areas. (Modulos = Financeiro, Estoque, Faturamento, etc)

Uso essa estrutura indiferente do tamanho do projeto, seja pequeno ou gigante

Minha dúvida é: 
Numa arquitetura, o número de dll's influencia em performance? escalabilidade?
Deixando assim seria ruim se meu projeto crescesse?

Ou seria melhor criar uma class library para cada módulo(uma class library para modulo financeiro, outra para faturamento, e assim por diante.
Assim como web project, um web project para financeiro, faturamento,etc.

Links sobre arquitetura são bem vindos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O único problema com múltiplas DLLs é um ligeiro aumento de tempo ao iniciar a aplicação, já que todas as DLLs serão localizadas e as suas dependências resolvidas, mas não vale a pena se preocupar com esse impacto na performance.

Answer (score 2):

O melhor para manutenção é você realmente separar, cada projeto com sua responsabilidade.

- Projeto - Layer - de acesso a dados (entity)
- Projeto - Layer - Utils (dll genéricas)
- Projetos - Layer - UI

Mas também deve ter um bom senso e não separar tudo. em 200 projetos.
Por exemplo no seu caso eu deixaria Entity e ORM tudo junto, afinal são as mesmas coisas.

a Utils deixaria junto com a BLL (Classes para manipulações da Entity)

Interessante também é verificar o que cada Classe sua faz, exemplo não criar uma classe muito genérica.
é melhor ter várias classes cada um fazendo apenas 1 única coisa. Ler sobre: Responsabilidade única.