# É possivel usar o entity framework a partir de uma bliblioteca de classes?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Normalmente eu uso o entity framework num projecto MVC mas eu gostaria de saber se posso usar apartir de um projecto de biblioteca de classes

Comment: Explique melhor o que está querendo fazer. Se eu entendi direito, não tem restrições, se for o seu objetivo.

Comment: Imagine que eu tenho as minhas classes de model na biblioteca de classes, e eu ai uso o EF para criar a base de dados posso fazer isso ou preciso de criar as classes dentro de um projecto MVC

Comment: Não sei te dizer com plena certeza, porque tanto o EF, quanto o MVC são meio "máqicos". Mas é possível que tenha algum problema no MVC, se bem que não deveria, não posso afirmar por desconhecer a arquitetura interna. Acho que depende da forma como faz. Quando você cria um projeto no Visual Studio de um tipo não tem nada de muito especial, ele cria uma série de coisas que você precisará. Mas é possível até criar um vazio, que só tem a configuração pronta para compilar de forma adequado para operar com um servidor web.

Comment: Pode. Nada impede.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é totalmente possível separar o projeto em **bibliotecas de classes**

<sub>até tem uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11771/numa-arquitetura-o-n%c3%bamero-de-dlls-influencia-em-performance-escalabilidade) aqui no SO-PT sobre desempenho</sub>

**Exemplo de como separar em projetos:**

Em uma solução em branco crie 3 projetos, sendo eles

i) **NomeProjeto.Classes** (aqui ficará as classes do projeto);

ii) **NomeProjeto.Entity** (aqui ficará as configurações do *entity*)

iii) **NomeProjeto.MVC** (aqui ficará a camada web)

Na camada de **classes**, crie uma classe, exemplo:

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Sexo { get; set; }
}
```

Na camada **Entity** instale o *entity* `Install-Package EntityFramework` pelo *package manager console* ou pelo `nuget`. Crie uma classe de contexto, exemplo:

```
public class EntitySeparadoDbContext : DbContext
{
    public EntitySeparadoDbContext()
    { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //No exemplo está sendo usuário o EntityTypeCOnfiguration para configurar como ficará a classe no banco
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PessoaConfiguration());
    }

    public DbSet<Pessoa> Pessoas { get; set; }
}
```

Após isso você pode habilitar as *migrations* (`enable migrations`), adiciona-las (`add-migration <nome>`) e executa-las (`update-database`)

OBS:É necessário no *package manager console* definir o projeto **Entity** como padrão, exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após isso, na camada **MVC** basta instanciar o contexto e usa-lo normalmente, exemplo:

```
private EntitySeparadoDbContext db = new EntitySeparadoDbContext();

public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Pessoa pessoa = db.Pessoas.Find(id);
    if (pessoa == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(pessoa);
}
```

Fiz um projeto exemplo e subi ele no [GitHub](https://github.com/leobarbetta/Entity-Separado)

Talvez você também queira ver sobre:

[Como implementar o Padrão Repository no C# com EF?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16122/como-implementar-o-padr%c3%a3o-repository-no-c-com-ef)

[O que é injeção de dependência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20770/o-que-%c3%a9-inje%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-depend%c3%aancia)